# TypeORM insert row with foreign key

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have a @OneToMany relation between
Chatroom < **1** ---- **M** > Messages
And the problem that I have is, whenever I try to insert a Message (or bulk of Messages),
The foreign key for ChatRoom is null.
In addition, I'm uploading my setup.

```
@Entity("messages")
export class Message {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => ChatRoom, chatroom => chatroom.messages)
    chatRoom: ChatRoom | undefined

    @Column({nullable: false})
    message: string;

    @Column({nullable: false})
    receiver: string;

    @Column({nullable: false})
    created_utc: Date;
}
```

```
@Entity("chatrooms")
export class ChatRoom {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Message, message => message.chatRoom, {
        cascade: ["insert", "remove"]
    })
    @JoinColumn({name: 'id'})
    messages: Message[];

    @Column()
    last_msg: string;

    @Column()
    last_msg_created_utc: Date;

    @Column()
    num_messages: number;

    @Column()
    num_replies: number;

    @Column()
    seen: boolean;

}
```

#### Problem:

When trying to create a bulk insert on many messages, I can notice that the query is not setting the foreign key any value, but **NULL**.

The Message json that I'm trying to insert:

```
{
 id: '1',
 message: 'text',
 receiver: 'someone',
 created_utc: 'utc date...',
 chatRoomId: '123' -> chat room id exists 
}

the query looks like this :
(this query is for single insert not bulk, but it goes the same for bulk)
INSERT INTO "messages"("id", "message", "receiver", "created_utc", "chatRoomId") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: [" bJU7","Zdravo test","kompir_zomba","2021-
09-05T09:53:54.693Z"]
```

This tells me that chatRoomId is not even taken into consideration when inserting the rows.
The table looks as following
[image]

The Typeorm insert query that I use to insert Messages

```
@InjectRepository(Message) private messageRepository: Repository<Message>
.....

    this.messageRepository.save(message);
```

Anyone has any idea how to proceed with this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue with TypeORM when working on a NestJS project.

### **Reason:**

The issue is happening because you don't have any `chatRoomId` field defined in your **Message Entity** (`class Message`). So, when TypORM maps your message data with the *Message entity*, it doesn't set the `chatRoomId`.

### **Solutions:**

There are two solutions to fix this problem.

1. You can add the `chatRoomId` field in your `Message` entity and now you will be able to send the field when saving the message data.

e.g.

```
@Column({type: "uuid"}) // <- Assuming that your primary key type is UUID (OR you can have "char")
chatRoomId: string;
```

> Now, usually you would not need to create a migration for this since
> this field already exists in the database table.

2. The other way is to pass an instance of `ChatRoom` entity to the `message` object when saving it.

You can, first, find the chat room using its ID and then pass it in the message object.

Your final `message` object should look like this:

```
{
 id: '1',
 message: 'text',
 receiver: 'someone',
 created_utc: 'utc date...',
 chatRoom: chatRoomData // <-- Assuming that chatRoomData contains the ChatRoom entity
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! After experimenting last night I got to your solution, but I didn't like it that much. 
Solution 1 is much cleaner and I like it. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Liki Glad to hear that it worked out for you. Indeed, the 1st solution is much cleaner with less code and overhead. Also, I would really appreciate if you could mark it as the accepted answer to your question. :) Thanks!

Comment: Of course, forgot that. 
And for future readers, for Solution 2, you don't need to pass all of the data (if you don't have cascade update..), you can only pass the Entity with ID field (others null), it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = await this.photosRepository.findOne(data.userId);
    if(!test){
        throw new NotFoundException("Exception message");
    }
    const myPhoto = await this.photosRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(Photo)
        .values({
            url: data.url,
            user:{
                id: data.userId
            }

        })
        .execute();

    console.log(myPhoto)
```

Hello, I tried to do it this way and it works fine.
Form 2 of the example above I did not understand well, could you upload an example? I am new at this

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when dealing with `OneToOne` `joins` TypeORM will know what to do and handle it for you.

```
  @Column("uuid", { name: "parent_id", nullable: true })
  parentId: string;

  @JoinColumn({ name: 'parent_id' }) <-- note the name here
  @OneToOne(() => MoveEntity)
  parent: MoveEntity | null;
```

ORM Handles Relationships: The ORM takes care of managing the relationship between moves based on the @OneToOne annotation and foreign key.

Optional parentId: You have the flexibility to set parentId to create hierarchical relationships or leave it null for moves without parents.