# TypeORM create a record with the ForeignKey

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities `questionnaires` and `sections`. A questionnaire has multiple sections so the relation is `OneToMany`.

When I try to create a new record for the questionnaire - it works just fine. I get an id and then I create a section record and reference the id there.

Response, when I try to create a section, is this

```json
{
  "name": "Section 1",
  "questionnaire_id": 1,
  "description": "Section 1 description",
  "id": 1
}
```

As you see it returns `questionnaire_id` back but the problem is that that record in DB is `questionnaire_id=null`. If I change it manually and assign an id value to it then it works and I get my JSON document with sections in it.

If I fetch all records from the DB then I get this

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Section 1",
    "description": "Section 1 description"
  }
]
```

`questionnaire_id` is not present because it's `null`. .

Do you know what I might be doing wrong? I have a feeling it has something to do with Entity relation but not sure what exactly.

```js
@Entity({ name: 'questionnaires' })
export class Questionnaire {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 128 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: STATUS, default: STATUS.ACTIVE })
  status: STATUS;

  @OneToMany(() => Section, (section) => section.questionnaire)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'questionnaire_id' })
  sections: Section[];
}
```

```js
@Entity({ name: 'sections' })
export class Section {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 128 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', default: '' })
  description: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Questionnaire, (questionnaire) => questionnaire.sections)
  questionnaire: Questionnaire;
}
```

The goal is to get all the questionnaires with their' sections.

The way I'm trying to achieve is this

```js
@Injectable()
export class QuestionnaireService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Questionnaire) private readonly questionnaire: Repository<Questionnaire>) {}

  create(createQuestionnaireDto: CreateQuestionnaireDto) {
    return this.questionnaire.save(createQuestionnaireDto);
  }

  findAll() {
    return this.questionnaire.find({
      relations: ['sections'],
    });
  }
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class SectionService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Section) private readonly sectionRepository: Repository<Section>) {}

  create(createSectionDto: CreateSectionDto) {
    return this.sectionRepository.save(createSectionDto);
  }

  findAll() {
    return this.sectionRepository.find();
  }
}
```

```js
export class CreateSectionDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Section name',
    example: 'Section 1',
  })
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MaxLength(128)
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Relation to the questionnaire',
    example: 1,
  })
  @IsNumber()
  questionnaire_id: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Section description',
    example: 'Section 1 description',
    default: '',
  })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  @MaxLength(512)
  description?: string;
}
```

p.s.

I checked this one [TypeORM insert row with foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062374/typeorm-insert-row-with-foreign-key)

but did not work for me.

EDIT:

This is what query is executed when running insert command

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO "sections"("created_at", "updated_at", "name", "description", "questionnaire_id") VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $1, $2, DEFAULT) RETURNING "created_at", "updated_at", "id", "description" -- PARAMETERS: ["Section 1","Section 1 description"]
query: COMMIT
```

I have "created_at", "updated_at" fields too but I did not include in the examples above.

As it's visible it includes `questionnaire_id` but for some reason the value is set to `DEFAULT`. Not passing the one I'm sending via http request.

## SOLUTION

The problem was my approach of creating records. Since I've set up a DB relation and the Section's table is dependent on the Questionnaire's table - TypeORM does not allow me to create sections records with my FK value. The library handles it automatically if I created Questionnaire first and assigned Sections object to it.

With the configration above the line below works just fine

```js
  async create(createQuestionnaireDto: CreateQuestionnaireDto) {
    const questionnaire = this.questionnaire.create(createQuestionnaireDto);
    const sections = new Section();
    sections.name = 'Default Section';
    sections.summary = 'Default Section Summary';
    sections.questionnaire = questionnaire;

    await this.questionnaire.save(questionnaire);
    await this.section.save(sections);

    return questionnaire;
  }
```

And the query it is running is this

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO "sections"("created_at", "updated_at", "name", "summary", "questionnaire_id") VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $1, $2, $3) RETURNING "created_at", "updated_at", "id", "summary" -- PARAMETERS: ["Default Section","Default Section Summary",1]
query: COMMIT
```

As you can see there is no `DEFAULT` for `questionnaire_id`.

If I wanted my initial approach to make work I should not be using TypeORM relation decorators, which is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: I don't use typeORM very often, does it provides log facility? If yes can you share the query which is executed when you create section?

Comment: Let me check if I can get the query

Comment: Edited the question. It does not have the field `questionnaire_id` so probably TypeORM related

Answer (score 1):

As I have not used TypeORM very often so I am not totally sure about the answer but you can check this out.

So you probably doing wrong in defining your Entity relation. You are using `@JoinColumn` in Questionnaire Entity.

It should be defined in Sections Entity like below:

```
@Entity({ name: 'sections' })
export class Section {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 128 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', default: '' })
  description: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Questionnaire, (questionnaire) => questionnaire.sections)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'questionnaire_id' })
  questionnaire: Questionnaire;
}
```

The answer is based on this document https://typeorm.io/relations#joincolumn-options. Hope it solves your issue.

**EDIT : (not related might be deprecated but mentioned in official docs)**
Are you sure loading relations this way works ?

```
findAll() {
    return this.questionnaire.find({
      relations: ['sections'],
    });
  }
```

As I can see in documents [HERE](https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations), they are doing something else.

```
findAll() {
    return this.questionnaire.find({
      relations: {
              sections: true,
         },
    });
  }
```

**EDIT 2:**

So if you now add a Column into your section entity like this it will work.

```
@Entity({ name: 'sections' })
export class Section {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 128 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', default: '' })
  description: string;

  @Column({ type: 'number' })
  questionnaire_id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Questionnaire, (questionnaire) => questionnaire.sections)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'questionnaire_id' })
  questionnaire: Questionnaire;
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried but it does not save `questionnaire_id`, the same result

Comment: I have edited my answer check it out and let me know if that works for you and please don't forget to check out the linked document.

Comment: I'm sure it works this way because when I manually edit `questionnaire_id ` and assign a value to it I get the expected result. Problem is that it is null on insert. I saw the same thing in docs but maybe its outdated because my ts compilet wont allow me to use that syntax you provlided. It expcets an array of strings.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the @JoinColumn decorator? Then try to add relation using method suggested in the documents. One thing I noticed is you are using nestjs so you are using @nestjs/typeorm package

Comment: The reason I'm using JoinColumn is to have custom column name. As docs say I can omit that but if I want to have a specific name for FK I can use it. If I remove that part it will name `questionnaires_id` instead of `questionnaire_id`. It does not change anythong I'll just have different column name.

Comment: I have edited my question check it out, hope it will work now and you will get your solution and want to add one more thing if you want that in some field you want `questionnaire_id` as null then just do `@Column({ type: 'number', nullable: true })` because by default it will not accept null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244086/discussion-between-jay-godhani-and-n1md7).

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was something else. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Welcome :). Your solution is the way that is mentioned in docs it works fine. If you want to create records as you were creating earlier then check edit 2 of my solution I have tested it and it works similar as you needed.